# Writing a matrix into a file in Java

Tags: java, file, matrix

I'm trying to write a graph format into a file in Java. 
The problem is I'm only able to write String types into a file.
I uploaded an image showing a 5 by 5 matrix, for example:
{{5,5,0,0,0},{0,1,0,1,0},{1,0,0,0,0},{0,0,1,0,0},{0,1,0,1,0},{0,0,0,0,0}}, while the first row describes and gives information on the following matrix - 5 rows, 5 columns.

My problem is I'm only able to write Strings into the file. I have tried to use String type and covert it to int, but it's messy a bit. Thanks a lot!

Comment: what do you want to do with the file afterwards? should it be readable by another program or by a user? maybe take a look serialization.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at it.
My main purpose is to be able to use this file for a variety of functions. If to be even more precise, my project is on the Clique Problem. First of all, I'd like to write a matrix into a file (as I said above). Secondly, I'll be using this file as a function input to use it for a variety of functions (finding the largest clique, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

So, your data is represented as a 2d array of integers? Since you can write strings to a file, consider converting your data to a string, e.g.:

```
int[][] data = {{5,5,0,0,0},{0,1,0,1,0},{1,0,0,0,0},{0,0,1,0,0},{0,1,0,1,0},{0,0,0,0,0}};
String str = java.util.Arrays.deepToString(data);
```

It will give you something like `[[5, 5, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, ...], ...]`.